# Preventing array from selecting duplicate values

Tags: php

I currently have a piece of code that is selecting random values from an array but I would like to prevent it from selecting duplicate values. How can I achieve this? This is my code so far:

```
$facilities = array("Blu-ray DVD Player","Chalk board","Computer", "Projector",
"Dual data projector", "DVD/Video");

for($j = 0; $j < rand(1, 3); $j++)
   {
    $fac =  print $facilities[array_rand($facilities, 1)] . '<br>'; 
   }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should look at `array_rand`

```
$facilities = array("Blu-ray DVD Player","Chalk board","Computer","Data projector","Dual data projector","DVD/Video");
$rand = array_rand($facilities, 2);
                                ^----- Number of values you want 

foreach ( $rand as $key ) {
    print($facilities[$key] . "<br />");
}
```

Comment: Why won't it work with `array_rand($facilities, 1);`. I've tried    `$rand = array_rand($facilities, rand(1, 3));` but it doesn't work

Comment: `echo $facilities[array_rand($facilities)] ;` that is how to get only one element

Answer (score 2):

You can return multiple random keys from [array_rand()](http://php.net/array_rand) by specifying the number to return as the second parameter.

```
$keys = (array) array_rand($facilities, rand(1, 3));
shuffle($keys); // array_rand() returns keys unshuffled as of 5.2.10

foreach ($keys as $key) {
    echo $facilities[$key] . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: The only thing worth pointing out is that this will fail ungracefully if `rand(1, 3)` is 1.